# Mongoose connection interrupted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am connected to a MongoDB server using mongoose.

When the connection to the MongoDB server is interrupted (e.g. the MongoDB server has shut down), all further actions, like `myModel.create(data, callback)`, won't fire the callback, but just does nothing.

In the meantime, mongoose tries to reconnect to the MongoDB server and fires constantly the handler defined with `mongoose.connection.on("error", handler)`

So here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to set a timeout for the callback of `myModel.create`? This would allow to cancel the request and notify the user that the database is currently unavailable.
2. Is it possible to limit the calls to the error handler?